# Cannot get the exact text from multiline using findall (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have multiline text like below

```
dbg = '''
HPLMN(424-03)  SIM_STATE(1)
SLOT 1 WITH DDS
SERVING PLMN(424-03) - LTE
SERVICE(AVAILABLE-2)
NW SEL: AUTO
ATT# 0, TAU# 0
EMM(REGISTERED-4) TAC(524)
LTE RRC: CONN BAND: 3
BW: 20.0MHZ
EARFCN: 1850, PCI: 445
R0 RSRP: -70, RSRQ: -6, SNR:34
R1 RSRP: -61, RSRQ :-6, SNR:34
RSRP:-61, RSRQ:-5, SNR:35
TX PWR: 1 DBM
PAGING_CYCLE: 640 MS
MOD(QAM): DL:256QAM, UL: -
CA ACTIVATED
(S1)BAND:20,BW:15.0MHZ
(S1)EARFCN:6375,PCI:445
(S1)RSRP:-60,RSRQ;-9,SNR:33
'''
```

I use the code below to get specific line only which is **"EARFCN: 1850, PCT: 445"**

```
items=re.findall('^EARFCN.*',dbg,re.MULTILINE)
```

but it return instead 2 lines

```
**EARFCN: 1850, PCT: 445**

**(S1)EARFCN:6375,PCI:445**
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results, and when I run your script I only get the desired single line.

Comment: I have run it again now and it gave the same result  ['EARFCN: 1850, PCI: 445', '(S1)EARFCN:6375,PCI:445']

Comment: Edit your question with the _exact_ script you are running.

Comment: I updated the text in the question

Comment: Still not reproducible.

Comment: That is strange why it keep happening with me !!

Comment: It doesn't happen to me either, the result I get is the expected one. What python version are you using? Could you try to reproduce your problem in a clean python console by pasting the script posted here?

Comment: I use python 3.11